# Overheating Diode

Tags: power-supply, transformer, diodes, power-electronics, rectifier

[image]

The mains supplies 240VAC, the transformer is rated at 240V/12-0-12V (Center tap), 3A. The load is made up of a single 12V 36 Watts PTC heater. The diode is T6A10 (Max forward current is 6A), The electrolytic capacitor is 1000uF 25V. The diode happens to overheat(can't touch without a burn) when the circuit is powered. What could be the reason?

Comment: the cause is too much current, calculate the RMS current in diode.


what is the purpose of the capacitor?

what is the purpose of the diode?

why not just connect the heater to 12V AC?

Comment: I have just realized after you commented, that the heaters use both AC and DC. I guess that I will resolve to AC after I fail to point out the problem. I added the capacitor to smooth out the ripples.

Comment: Resolve to AC right now, you don't have to filter current to a heater – the heating does.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I recommend that you check the datasheet for your transformer. You said: "*the transformer is rated at 240V/12-0-12V (Center tap), 3A*" Some manufacturers might mean that each side of the center-tap is rated at 3A, but some might mean that the *total* rated secondary current is 3A and each side of the center-tap secondary is therefore rated at half of that i.e. 1.5A in your case. In the latter case, you are overloading the half of the transformer secondary which you are using, with your 3A (36 W) load.

Comment: If you have look to datasheet you can easily reckon some 40 to 50 Celsius junction  temp rise even in best case of resistive 3A load. There it comes that your finger will feel 70+ degrees which is enough to burn.

Comment: If you REALLY need to rectify for some other reason, consider using a "MOSFET ideal diode" circuit or device.

Answer (score 2):

This is a half-wave rectifier circuit so the diode only conducts during positive half cycles of the AC mains. Therefore the peak diode current will be much higher than the average and [rms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) current drawn by the load. At higher current the diode drops more voltage so its power dissipation will also be higher than it would be for the equivalent DC current.

I simulated your circuit in [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/), and graphed the results over two cycles (red =  diode current, Blue = capacitor current, Green = load voltage):-

[image]

The first thing we notice is that the capacitor is not large enough to hold the voltage up much during negative half cycles. This is fortunate because if it did the load would get close to 16V. With 1000uF it still gets 16V peak, but only 8.4V rms (and 2.1A rms). However the capacitor has to be recharged every half cycle, which increases the peak diode current.

Diode current rises to over 6A while charging the capacitor, rms current is ~3A (50% higher than the load current) and average power dissipation is ~1.3W. The capacitor is also working hard with 5A peak and 2.1A rms.

But if the diode is rated for 6A and only passing ~3A, why is it getting so hot? The answer is that it can handle much higher temperatures than your finger can withstand. This diode rated for 6A at up to 60°C ambient, with an expected temperature rise of 90°C (a good design would run it at lower current to reduce surface temperature and improve reliability).

> The load is made up of a single 12V 36 Watts PTC heater.

This heater should work equally well on AC current, so the rectifier and filter are just wasting power and reducing the available voltage.

If for some reason you *need* to power the heater with DC then you should use a full wave rectifier circuit with a diode off each transformer output winding. Two diodes will run cooler because they are sharing the load, and you may not need a smoothing capacitor because the raw rectified output voltage should be close to 12V rms.